# Issue with JAXB generated with xjc

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an issue with JAXB for the following xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">


        <xs:complexType name="data">
            <xs:sequence  maxOccurs="2">
                <xs:element name="indg1" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="indg2" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="indg3" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="sample" type="data" />
</xs:schema>
```

The following class is generated:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "data", propOrder = {
    "indg1AndIndg2AndIndg3"
})
public class Data {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "indg1", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "indg2", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "indg3", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<String>> indg1AndIndg2AndIndg3;

    public List<JAXBElement<String>> getIndg1AndIndg2AndIndg3() {
        if (indg1AndIndg2AndIndg3 == null) {
            indg1AndIndg2AndIndg3 = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>>();
        }
        return this.indg1AndIndg2AndIndg3;
    }

}
```

What I was expecting was a class by the name of "Sample" with `List<Data>`. 
Can you tell me how to do it, and why the behavior above is as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the generated class ObjectFactory. It contains a method for creating an element sample using an instance of class Data. The top level element of a document doesn't need a class of its own.

You are getting this strange `List<JAXBElement<String>>` because you have a repetition of a sequence of heterogeneous elements.

Comment: Oh ... sometimes you get confused .. i just forget that "sample" is the root node and rest are child nodes of root :D hence the above behavior is right just the wrong naming "indg1AndIndg2AndIndg3". Do you have a work around for that or should i use the age old tradition "do it manually".

Comment: IS the XML structure really two times indg1, indg2, indg3? If you change the XSD only minimally by adding the maxOccurs=2 to these three elements, you'll get three nicely named Lists. Somehow, xjc has to arrive at a name for the List.